# NumPy - How would I vectorize this operation?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to take an array of dimension  `(M, 4)` and subtract elements to return an array of `(M, 2)`.

For example:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8]]

# to

[[2, 2],
 [2, 2]]
```

What I've tried was the following:

```
subs = a[..., 2] - a[..., 0], a[..., 3] - a[..., 1]
```

But that returns in the manner of 2 arrays with dimension `(M,)`.

Comment: So you basically want to do `a[:,2:] - a[:,:2]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make views of your array, and then subtract the two views, like:

```
a[:,2:] - a[:,:2]
```

For example for some sample input:

```
>>> a
array([[5, 2, 9, 2],
       [9, 9, 7, 9]])
>>> a[:,2:] - a[:,:2]
array([[ 4,  0],
       [-2,  0]])
```